# Returning non-overlapping records within a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data. I have looked over a lot of threads about overlapping and non-overlapping dates but none seemed to help me.

```
===============================
PK  | StartDate  |  EndDate
===============================
1   | 2016-05-01 |  2016-05-02
2   | 2016-05-02 |  2016-05-03
3   | 2016-05-03 |  2016-05-04
4   | 2016-05-04 |  2016-05-05
5   | 2016-05-07 |  2016-06-08
===============================
```

From this table with a SQL query I want to return the first record out of overlapping dates
or basically

```
===============================
PK  | StartDate  |  EndDate
===============================
1   | 2016-05-01 |  2016-05-02
3   | 2016-05-03 |  2016-05-04
5   | 2016-05-07 |  2016-06-08
===============================
```

I have been struggling a lot with this query and was wondering if this is actually possible without too much of a hit on performance and whether its better if thats done on backend or with a SQL query because I believe it'd be easier for me to do it on the backend.

Comment: Mysql or (MS)SQL-Server?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I'd get more help if I tag both. Its (MS)SQL-Server.

Comment: MS SQL Server vs MySQL is your DBMS aka what database platform you are using. By definition you can't be on both. They are similar in concepts, but specific syntax can be very different. It's like tagging a question Mac and Windows, sure both are Operating Systems and can do similar things, but their approach is very different. And not knowing which platform you are on, makes your question harder to answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be 2016-05-01 |  2016-05-05 and 2016-05-07 |  2016-05-08? as there is no gap from 02 to 03?

Comment: No, I need to retrieve the first record when the dates overlap - then we exclude the ones the first one overlaps with and then we return the second record which doesn't overlap with the first returned as it is in the second schema provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating a new column and partitioning it to fetch only first rows.

```
declare @tbl table
(pk int identity,StartDate date,EndDate date)

insert into @tbl
values('2016-05-01','2016-05-02')
,('2016-05-02','2016-05-03')
,('2016-05-03','2016-05-04')
,('2016-05-04','2016-05-05')
,('2016-05-07','2016-06-08')

select pk,startdate,enddate  from(select pk,startdate,enddate 
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by [overlappingdates] order by startdate)rn
from(
select *,case when ROW_NUMBER()over(order by startdate) % 2 = 0 
then StartDate else EndDate end as [overlappingdates]
from
@tbl
)t
)t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. It does solve the problem. How slow would that query be if it had to process 500k records?

Comment: @squezzi To be honest I can't answer this question since the performance context can be dealt with only to a certain extent and rest solely depend on how rich the server is (in terms of specifications/configuration). Since the table has to be scanned to identify the overlapping dates, this query must be tested live to assess the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Need to join to first find all overlapping, unpivot to dates in columns, then just find the MIN(dates).

### Min of Start/End of Overlapping Date Ranges

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Dates
CREATE TABLE #Dates (PK INT IDENTITY(1,1),StartDate DATE,EndDate DATE)
INSERT INTO #Dates VALUES
('2016-05-01','2016-05-02')
,('2016-05-02','2016-05-03')
,('2016-05-03','2016-05-04')
,('2016-05-04','2016-05-05')
,('2016-05-07','2016-06-08')

SELECT A.PK
    ,StartDate = MIN(C.StartDate)
        ,EndDate = MIN(C.EndDate)
FROM #Dates AS A
INNER JOIN #Dates AS B
    ON A.PK < B.PK /*Only join 1 way and don't join to itself*/
    /*Find any overlap*/
    AND A.StartDate <= B.EndDate
    AND A.EndDate >= B.StartDate
CROSS APPLY (VALUES /*Puts in unpivoted(vertical) format so can run MIN() function*/
                (A.StartDate,A.EndDate)
                ,(B.StartDate,B.EndDate)
) AS C(StartDate,EndDate)           
GROUP BY A.PK
```